Branch off one branch, and merge to another
Is it okay to merge off one short lived branch, and then merge back into the short lived branch's successor?

The develop branch is a descendent of trunk.
Imagine for example branching from develop to release/week-1.
Then finding a bug, and branching from release/week-1 to fixes/fix-bug.
The bug isn't fixed instantly, and is no show stopper. So we release anyway.
So release/week-1 gets merged into master.
A week later release/week2 is created.
Now we finally merge fixes/fix-bug, but into release/week2.

Is it safe and okay in git to structurally work this way? Or should you always aim to merge to an ancestor branch? The reason I ask this, is I want to use a similar technique for two teams that work with different release cycles in the same code base.
develop     ______________________________
release/*     \_______/\    \_______/\    
fixes/*           \_____\_____/       \   
master      _____________\_____________\__


Since release/week-1 got merged into develop, and release/week2 branched from develop, your fixes/fix-bug is still branched off from release/week2 (just at an earlier parent).

You would be fine doing that. However, once the bug-fix was developed off of release/week-1 but you chose not to merge back into release/week-1, you still had the option of merging or rebasing the bug-fix to develop after merging release/week1 to develop (as part of starting work on a new release), threreby treating it like a normal bug-fix during normal development. I don't see an advantage to waiting to merging it into release/week2 branch. (The naming conventions look like Gitflow, so maybe its a Gitflow thing.)

What you do is absolutly fine. I would not recommend to rebase the branch, because by leaving it branched off as early as possible you can merge it into other branches that may need the fix.

To highlight Raymond Chen's comment:

Since release/week-1 got merged into develop, and release/week2 branched from develop, your fixes/fix-bug is still branched off from release/week2 (just at an earlier parent).

This is true because when you branch off of another branch, like so:

Imagine for example branching from develop to release/week-1.
...
Then finding a bug, and branching from release/week-1 to fixes/fix-bug.

Note that Git doesn't actually retain a memory of the branch name you create a branch from. Branch names are pointers to a commit ID. This means that when you created fixes/fix-bug from release/week-1, what you actually did was create a branch called fixes/fix-bug which points to the same commit ID that release/week-1 was pointing to at the time you ran the command.
After release/week-1 was merged into develop, now that commit that you started from is also in develop, so it would be correct to say that fixes/fix-bug came from an older commit from develop.
Since release/week-2 also came from develop, it is also correct to say that fixes/fix-bug came from an older commit from release/week-2.
If we erase irrelevant lines from the original diagram, we get this:
                __         _____             
release/week2     \_______/     \_______/     
fixes/fix-bug         \___________/          

Which straightens out to
release/week2 _____________________
fixes/fix-bug     \___________/          

which looks like a perfectly normal "create a feature branch for the fix and merge it back."
Therefore, you can absolutely merge fixes/fix-bug into release/week-2. It's no different than if you had branched off of develop a while back. If you wish to (or need to in order to resolve conflicts) update your branch with the latest release/week-2 you certainly can. (Use rebase or merge as directed by the repo owner.)
Conclusion:

Is it safe and okay in git to structurally work this way? Or should you always aim to merge to an ancestor branch?

In this case, the ancestor branch, and release/week-2, both contain the same merge-base with your branch, so it doesn't make a difference.

As TTT and Raymond Chen have explained it is irrelevant in this
case. But in general I think caring about ancestor and successor
branches misses the point. You ought to branch off and merge so as to
propagate changes in the correct way. And the branching strategy
dictates that.
What if you branched off on week-1 but only fixed it while working on
week-5? Do you want it to go directly to develop or should week-5
get it? You don’t explain what the point of all these branches are so
this cannot be answered.
A release candidate example
Your only branch currently is main. You are about to create a new
release 1.0. You create a release candiate on main named
1.0-rc. You need this branch because you only want some changes to go
into the next release; there are some pending changes that you think are
too risky to land in the next release, but you want them in main.
Now you have some branch which was created a year ago with a fix. Do you
merge it to 1.0-rc or main? It is irrelevant whence the branch was
created—only where you want the change. Too risky for the release?
Merge it to main. A crucial fix for the next release? Merge it to
1.0-rc.
Propagating changes
As soon as you have a new non-feature branch you need to determine the
relationship it has to the original branch. main should probably be a
superset of 1.0-rc. So once you merge the fix to 1.0-rc you merge
1.0-rc into main.
Backporting fixes
Say you have five releases. It turns out that some installations are on
the two oldest versions and they are not ready for a new release (the
sixth one). But they need an incoming fix. Thus you need three merges:

Into a release branch for the oldest branch
Then a merge from that release branch into the second-oldest release
branch
And from (2) into main

